# Retrieve list of javascript cookies from remote URL

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I create a list of javascript cookies (for example google analytics _utmz cookies) from a remote URL?

I am able to get the http cookies by getting the http header. Is there any way to execute 'document.cookie' for example on a remote URL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can only get cookies for the domain the site is on.

The only other option is to use an iframe from that domain, but that still requires you having control of the domain in question in order for you to do anything with the information.

EDIT:

If you are trying to get cookies from the same domain as the webpage, use:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

getCookie("analytics _utmz");

(See example at the much-hated [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp))

Comment: Thanks, but when I go to any site and press F12 (in chrome this opens developer tools) and open the console and type: document.cookies I get the list of cookies. Any option to do this programatically ?

Comment: Not from another website. It's a security issue. You can use `document.cookie` from your site's Javascript. It will give you the cookies set by your domain only.

Comment: Thanks again, but when i use document.cookie from my clients browser in the console. I do get these cookies. Do you know if there is a way to simulate this browser console on server side?

Comment: When you do document.cookie in the console, you get the cookies for THAT domain.

Comment: You dont understand my question i guess. I want the cookies for THAT domain. On my client, i go to www.google.com , open the console and type document.cookie. Then i go to www.cnn.com , open the console and type document.cookie. This all works well and i get the list i want. How can i do this from a PHP script for example. Using an iframe or something?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for a website to access the cookies set by another site for obvious security reasons.

e.g. Alice visits Bob's website and logs in. Bob's site sets a cookie in Alice's browser that  proves she is logged in. Alice visits Malory's website. If Malory could read the cookie that Bob set for Alice, then Malory could easily pretend to be Alice and get access to all the data Alice stored on Bob's site.